# Forecast scores, proper scores and strictly proper scores

Tags: predictive-models, scoring-rules

Let $\mu_F$ and $\sigma_F^2$ be the expectation and variance of a forecast model $F$ for observations $y$, and let $p_F(\cdot)$ denote the probability density function for the forecast model. Also let $G$ be a different forecast model.

Which of the following statements are true?

1. Two forecast scores $S(F,y)$ and $S(G,y)$ are independent
2. The squared error $(y-\mu_F)^2$ is a proper score
3. The score $(y-\mu_F)^2/\sigma_F^2$ is a proper score that improves on the squared error score by taking the variance into account.
4. The logarithmic score $-\log(p_F(y))$ is a strictly proper score

EDIT:

Intuitively, I think 1 is false since $S(F,y)$ and $S(G,y)$ are both functions of their respective forecast model and the random variable $Y$.

2 should be true.

I think 3 is probably false as I can't derive anything meaningful when simply dividng by $\sigma_F^2$.

I'm not sure how to do the computation in this case but as far as I know the logarithmic score is strictly proper, so 4 should be true.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.